# Create Object with Nil Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a simple to_do model in my app with the following attributes: title:string, completed:boolean, completed_at:datetime, user_id:integer, project_id:integer.

```
class ToDo < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :project
end
```

On the create page there is a form that lets you submit a new to_do and lets you select a project to assign it to from a drop-down list of projects. This works perfectly.

I want to also be able to allow users to create to_dos that are not assigned to a project so I added `include_blank: true` to the collection_select of projects in the new to_do form which submits a project_id of "" to the backend.

When I submit a new to_do with a blank project_id I get the following error:

"Project must exist"

How can I allow for a nil project_id on the ToDo model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is new behavior in Rails 5, as described in [this blog post](https://jasoncharnes.com/belongs-to-required-rails-5/). In Rails 4 and earlier, if you wanted to ensure a `belongs_to` association existed, you had to explicitly state this using a validation. In Rails 5, the validation is automatic unless you set the `optional: true` flag in your model.

You need to specify that the `:project` association is optional, like this:

```
class ToDo < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :project, optional: true
end
```

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks so much!